# Twig remove indentation whitespace

Tags: html, whitespace, twig

I have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/junior87/8UrLY/). In order to obtain readability of the html markup I newlined' every inline element and indented it (1 tab = 4 spaces). Every element is appended a whitespace character `&nbsp;`. When I take a look at the DOM using Chrome v18.0.1025.162 browser I noticed there is the whitespace I expect using the `&nbsp` but then there is another whitespace character. As far as I know the browser should only show the `&nbsp;` and one whitespace from the indented next line (e.g. two indentation tabs are 8 spaces collapsed into one -> which I don't want).

When I use `{ % spaceless %} ... {% endspaceless %}` nothing changes. The documentation says:

> The first newline after a template tag is removed automatically (like in PHP.) Whitespace is not further modified by the template engine, so each whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.) is returned unchanged.

It seems that only with inline elements whitespace tabs are *not* ignored and display. Is it because its within a block element and whitespaces are preserved?

**How can I remove the whitespace (from indentation) then?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working by simply removing the extra `&nbsp;` entities. The new line with the indentation of the elements using whitespace (1 tab = 4 spaces) still creates one whitespace, but since I want to have that it's okay so far and keeps the markup readable. Does not feel right, or let's say it would feel better if I got more input on that issue.